# return a list of symbols of an ETF

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, finance, datareader

I want to write a function that enters a symbol of an ETF and the function returns a list of symbols of its components.

The function is almost there but there is an issue: I don't know why the `get_table()` line returns an error and this code only opens my Chrome browser but does not return a `pd.DataFrame` object as it should. I wonder why it happens and how to fix it?

```
import pandas as pd

# from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_etf_holdings(etf_symbol):
    
    url = 'https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/{}/constituents?page=all'.format(
        etf_symbol)

    # Loads the ETF constituents page and reads the holdings table
    browser = WebDriver() # webdriver.PhantomJS()
    browser.get(url)
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html')
    table = get_table(soup)

    # Reads the holdings table line by line and appends each asset to a
    # dictionary along with the holdings percentage
    asset_dict = {}
    for row in table.select('tr')[1:-1]:
        try:
            cells = row.select('td')
            # print(row)
            symbol = cells[0].get_text().strip()
            # print(symbol)
            name = cells[1].text.strip()
            celltext = cells[2].get_text().strip()
            percent = float(celltext.rstrip('%'))
            shares = int(cells[3].text.strip().replace(',', ''))
            if symbol != "" and percent != 0.0:
                asset_dict[symbol] = {
                    'name': name,
                    'percent': percent,
                    'shares': shares,
                }
        except BaseException as ex:
            print(ex)
    browser.quit()
    return pd.DataFrame(asset_dict)
```

Comment: And where is the `get_table(...)` function?

Answer (score 0):

The barchart website is very likely to prevent robots access in order to enforce their terms of use. To test and debug the code itself it might be better to access websites that are more flexible.